# WPF NotifyIcon - Hide Tray Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon

I'm currently using the (awesome) third party [WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon)

I've created a Tray Popup like so:

```
    <tb:TaskbarIcon Name="tbIcon" IconSource="/Images/Icon.ico" PopupActivation="LeftOrRightClick" TrayMouseDoubleClick="tbIcon_TrayMouseDoubleClick">
        <tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayPopup>
            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Width="auto" Height="auto">
                    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="btnSetupTray" Content="Setup" Margin="5" Width="70" Click="btnSetupTray_Click"></Button>
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="btnExitTray" Content="Exit" Margin="5" Width="50" Click="btnExit_Click"></Button>
                    </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayPopup>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

I'm wondering how I can hide the tray popup programatically.

I've tried setting the tray popup visibility:

```
 tbIcon.TrayPopup.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

which doesn't actually draw focus from the popup, meaning I have to double click another window to action something (like a button). It also means I have to set the visibility to `Visible` after focus has been drawn away from the popup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `IsOpen` instead of `Visibility` property. It is weird, but is has setter which actually closes the popup.

```
tbIcon.TrayPopup.IsOpen = false;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wonder why it's the accepted answer, since it doesn't work with the current version of Hardcodet WPF NotifyIcon. `TrayPopup` is `UIElement` type, it has no `IsOpen` accessor. However `TrayPopupResolved` does.

Comment: @Harry Maybe because this answer is for version from year 2015 and you are using 4 years newer version? :)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
tbIcon.TrayPopupResolved.IsOpen = false;
```